# WMQ Security Exit UserID/PWD passing issue

Tags: c, api, ibm-mq, mq

We are currently implementing a security exit for our SVRCONN channels. This exit will authenticate to our LDAP(AD or UNIX). Our current implementation of the exit is working for only connections coming from MQ EXPLORER.

When we write a code to connect and pass the userID/PWD, the security exit is picking up the user account login on the client machine.

Here is a snippet on how we connect to MQ

Code:

```
MQCNO ConnectOptions = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};
MQCD ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT}; 
MQCSP mqCSP = {MQCSP_DEFAULT}; 
MQHCONN HConn; 
MQLONG CompCode; 
MQLONG Reason; 
char QMName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH+1]="QMGRNAME"; 
char channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH+1]="MY_CHANNEL"; 
char hostname[1024]="MQSERVER(PORT)"; 
char UserId[32+1]="MyID"; 
char Password[32+1]="MyPWD"; 
strncpy(ClientConn.ConnectionName, hostname, MQ_CONN_NAME_LENGTH); 
strncpy(ClientConn.ChannelName, channelName, MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH); 
mqCSP.AuthenticationType = MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD; 
mqCSP.Version = MQCSP_VERSION_1; 
mqCSP.CSPUserIdPtr = &UserId; 
mqCSP.CSPUserIdOffset = 0; 
mqCSP.CSPUserIdLength = strlen(UserId); 
mqCSP.CSPPasswordPtr = &Password; 
mqCSP.CSPPasswordOffset = 0; 
mqCSP.CSPPasswordLength = strlen(Password); 
ConnectOptions.SecurityParmsPtr = &mqCSP; 
ConnectOptions.SecurityParmsOffset = 0; 
ConnectOptions.ClientConnPtr = &ClientConn; 
ConnectOptions.Version = MQCNO_VERSION_5; 
MQCONNX (QMName, &ConnectOptions, &HConn, &CompCode, &Reason);
```

Then we use this code to retrieve the userID/PWD on the security exit. 
Code:

```
memset (User, 0, pChDef->LongRemoteUserIdLength);
memset (Pass, 0, MQ_PASSWORD_LENGTH); 
MakeCString(User,pChDef->LongRemoteUserIdPtr,pChDef->LongRemoteUserIdLength); 
MakeCString(Pass,pChDef->RemotePassword,MQ_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
```

MQ Server->7.1.0.2

Comment: Please use the code markup for code instead of blockquote. Remove the `>` and replace with 4 spaces.

Comment: @laalto done editing.

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world would you re-invent the wheel when there is a cheap product that does authentication against an LDAP server?  If you spent more than a day programming this, you instead could have purchased a license for MQ Authenticate Security Exit and done something else.

MQ only flows the password in plain text.  Very easy to grab that password if you are familiar with MQ or just use WireShark since it knows/understands MQ protocol.

MQ uses 2 different styles of flowing the UserID and Password between a client and server: "old" and "new" style. Different platforms support different styles.  Some support both directly and some support both indirectly and some platforms do a conversion and flow both at the same time (very weird!).

It is fine if all of your applications can be rebuilt to use MQCONNX by what if the application cannot be rebuilt?  Or the application team does not want to do it or the source code is lost.  What about 3rd party applications that do not support MQCONNX?  What are you going to do?

What about MQ JNDI or CCDT (Client Channel Table Definitions) or the new "MQClient.ini" file?  Have you thought about how you are going to handle these implementations?

You are going to easily spend 6 months (i.e. 1000 hours) building a working prototype that covers some of the issues I have highlighted.  You are in for a world of hurt.  I know, I've been there done that.